# IntelliJ 2017.5: When building for android, I have to restart IntelliJ to get changes to my LibGDX project to take effect

Tags: java, intellij-idea, libgdx

Both "Recompile Player.java" (a class that has an obviously visible line to change) and "Rebuilt Project" do not seem to rebuild things -- running my application after using either of those does not pick up the changes I made. Quitting IntelliJ and starting it up again does cause the changes to be picked up.

Interestingly, the changes do appear to take effect immediately when I build for desktop, but my primary target is android right now, so I would like to get it working.

It was working correctly a few days ago. At the time that the misbehavior started, I was running 2017.3.

The things I have tried:
* upgrading to 2017.5
* updating system and rebooting
* uninstalling IntelliJ (removing from the /opt directory), and reinstalling 2017.3
* removing the .idea and .gradle directories from my project directory and then importing the project folder again

I've honestly been having a hard time finding the right google terms for trying to resolve this, and I'm coming up short. I don't *think* this is due to libgdx since I had a similar problem on occasion (but not always) on Android Studio in the past.

Comment: May be it is due to `Instant Run`, try to disable Instant Run and check result

Comment: Aha! Disabling instant run solved the problem.  Abishek, I'm not sure how to mark your comment as the correct answer?

Comment: @Tux okay, I posted as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to disable Instant Run in Android Studio

**To disable Instant Run:**

1. Open the Settings or Preferences dialog.
2. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run.
3. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.